# Sort RGB list of colors by least distance

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, colors, rgb

I am looking to sort a list of RGB colors by their least distance, and hopefully this will give a better sorting than Luminosity and HSV. I am using the distance formula to calculate the color's distance, but How can I sort the list based on the least distance?

Comment: what structure are you holding the colors in? an array?

Comment: You would define a Comparator, and use it with `Collections.sort`.

Comment: What do you mean by "least distance"? Least distance from what?  In order to sort something you have to have an absolute scale on which to place each value, and the relation must satisfy basic ordering requirements, such as transitivity.  If you don't have this you cannot sort consistently.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do. As somebody else asked, "Least distance from what?" What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget that you've got colours for a second, and simply consider points in 3D (or 2D) space.

You can't simply "sort" points by distance. You can sort them by distance to some specified point X, but that is probably not what you're after.

Instead what you're probably looking for is an ordering of the points that minimizes the total length of the path through them. This is essentially the traveling salesman problem, and its a *lot* more computationally intensive than just sorting the list.

Ideally you want to perform this distance calculation using a perceptually correct distance function - which usually means converting your points to Lab space and them using one of the standards.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways of doing this, you could use a comparator as suggested by @yshavit.

What I would do is create a new class and assign a color type plus a comparison value double, create a new array and then sort the colors based on their double values (smallest first etc) and then extract the colors out again.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you actually want to do it might be better to use a different colors space, e.g.: CIEDE2000.
There is a command-line tool that can measure perceptual color difference using that color space: [Ciff](https://github.com/kallaballa/Ciff)

Usage: ciff <24bit hex color> <24bit hex color>

For example the difference between white and black reports a distance of 100 (which is the maximum):

```
$ ciff ffffff 000000
100
```

Based on this tool (or the corresponding code)  you could easily write some code to do the sorting (simply using brute force if there aren't too many colors).

(I am the author of Ciff)

Comment: [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) - specifically you need to make it very clear that you're recommending your own tool

Comment: Didn't know this was good practice. Thx for the hint.